# In zshell curl returns a 400 bad request response when reading payload data from a file, but successful response when payload data is manually input?

Tags: shell, curl, zsh

I am using curl to send a POST request and the payload variable giving me trouble is converted to an instance of UUID on the backend of the API. When hardcoding the payload values, as shown below this line, I receive a successful response.

```
curl --request POST '<url>' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"id": "4312-3532-1244-3413",
"otherValue": "also_hardcoded"
}'
```

But when reading the data for the "id" variable from a file, I get an error response "400: Bad Request". Sample of what that request looks like below:

```
while read -r LineFromFile; do
   curl --request POST '<url>' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   --data-raw '{
   "id": "$LineFromFile",
   "otherValue": "also_hardcoded"
   }'
done < "$1"
```

Even though the text file only contains the same value as "id" in the first example. I tried using IFS=$'\n' in case a newline character was being discreetly read but that did not have any effect. I thought it could be an end of file issue, but adding duplicate lines with the same value to the text file only causes there to be more 400: Bad Request responses.

Can someone help me determine why the file is not being read the way I expected it to? Thank you very much. I greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Why is this tagged zsh and bash? Only tag the one you're using.

Comment: The shell does not expand variables inside of single quotes.

Comment: @Shawn I'm using zshell but I think they behave the same in this scenario, and way more people follow bash tag so I figured that would help much more in getting an answer. I apologize as I'm sure that's poor etiquette.

Comment: @jordanm Wow thank you... that was the issue